# Get paypal ruccuring payment details

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal payment gateway for recurring payment purpose but i want to get details of each done  weekly/monthly/yearly payment when payment made on each recurrence .
Can anybody help me? or suggest me how can i check recurring payment has made or not& get there details for each week/month/year.

Thanks 
Amol

Answer (score 0):

i got solution
I have set notification url in my paypal account
this url hit every transaction so i got all details for that transaction  when transaction done.
Notification url is url of my project where i want request data.